# How to clasify an unlabelled dataset with a newly trained NaiveBayes classifier in Weka

Tags: classification, weka, bayesian

I have an unlabeled dataset that I want to classify with my newly trained classifier using NaiveBayes classification in Weka. So actually when in the Classify mode in weka if i give the option Supplied Test set, then it accepts the test set only if it is labelled and evaluates and gives the accuracy. 
But what I want is to train it using a train.csv or train.arff file and then give it a new unseen and unlabelled test.csv or test.arff file and classify it and give it labels depending on classes in the training file. But if I provide an unlabelled file as test file to wweka it gives:

> ERROR: Train and Test set not compatible

Sample format of my Train and test files are as below:

```
Train.csv file:
article story .......hockey class
1       0     ...... 0      politics
0       0     .......1      sports
.
.
.
.
.                           sports
```

and Test.csv file:

```
article story .......hockey class
0       1     ...... 0      
1       0     .......1      
.
.
.
.
.
```

So how do I classify an unlabelled dataset in Weka using NaiveBayes classifier??

Comment: If my answer helped you clarifying ideas, you can accept my answer by right clicking on the "check" mark beside the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are missing the class label. Weka requires training and test set to have the exact same attributes in the same order. Now there are two cases:

**You know the classes of your test set**

The performance is calculated by comparing the actual class labels with the predicted ones. You need to supply the class labels in your test set like you did in your training set.

**You DON'T know the classes of your test set**

To calculate a performance, Weka needs to compare the predicted classes with the actual classes. If you don't have the actual classes, you cannot calculate the performance. You can only predict classes.
You have to add a `class` label with missing values for your test instances if you just want prediction.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your test set is labelled, Weka will not see it at first stage. It will use the classifier you developed with training data and then will apply the classifier on the test set you supply. The classifier then predicts each instance class and Weka then keeps track of a correct or incorrect classification. So, what you are doing here is exactly what you are trying to achieve. The error is telling that the training and test sets are not compatible because I believe you have removed the "class" label from the test set. Don't worry. Keep it as it is and the accuracy you are getting from Weka is the actual performance of the classifier. Hope that helps.

Comment: You're right about the class label, but the rest is wrong. How can Weka calculate a performance when it only has the predicted classes, but not the actual ones?

Answer (score 0):

you cant leave it all empty, you need to set at least one each class label on the class field (as some kind of "clue" for the weka)

- article story .......hockey class
- 0       1     ...... 0      politics
- 1       0     .......1      sport
- 1       1     .......1      ?
- 1       1     .......1      ?

the two first row will provide weka an example of the prediction class. Then you can predict as much as instance with no class (?) using your trained model